# how do i enter the value in one EditText and get answer in other EditText android

Tags: android

I have two EditText fields,whenever i enter the value in one editText,the other should display the answer for one calculation that taking the value of first editText,Iam unsure how to do this,**thanks in advance**(android)

Comment: what calculation you want to do and on which event?

Comment: use **OnTextChangeListener** on the EditText

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using **EditText's onKeyListener** event, you can also show result when specific key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextWatcher and update the content of the target on each change.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for this question is **.addTextChangedListener()**

you can use it by this code:

```
editText_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    //Your Codes
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // if editText_1 become null or "" 
                    editText_1.setText("0");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```